# coord_cartesian doesn't work in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Try to dynamic change the graph using coord_cartesian in my shiny app, however, I kept got Error:missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed. If I remove the coord_cartesian, the plot shows up but not dynamically zoom anymore.
Here are the sample codes: for input values

```
sliderInput(inputId = "xrange",'Day range',min=-30 ,max=60,value=c(0,15))
```

reactive to get xrange values:

```
  xrange <- reactive({
    cbind(input$xrange[1],input$xrange[2])
  })
```

renderPlot to reflect dynamically change:

```
 output$lineplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=city_predicted(),aes(x =day, y=value))+ 
      geom_line(aes(group=variable,colour=variable),lty=5)+
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0),lty=15)+
      geom_line(data=city_selected(),aes(x=day, y=value),lty=1)+
      ylab('Measures')+
      xlab('Days from Now')+
      scale_x_continuous()+
      coord_cartesian(xlim = xrange())+ 
      theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
      facet_wrap(.~variable)
  })
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: maybe `c(input$xrange[1],input$xrange[2])` instead?

Comment: or just `coord_cartesian(xlim = c(input$xrange[1], input$xrange[2])) + `